# AngularFire2 return Observable to ngrx effects

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, ngrx

I have a project built with Angular 4, ngrx and AngularFire2.  I am trying to retrieve the uid of the currently logged in user and put it in my store.

Any ideas or assistance would be appreciated.

**Error**

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (auth.effects.ts:22)
```

**Effects Code**

```
    @Effect() getAccountId$ = this.actions$
            .ofType(ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID)
            .map(action =>
// This is line 22 where the error is coming
                this.authService.getCurrentUserId() 
                    .map(authObject => ({ type: ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID_SUCCESS, payload: authObject }))
                    .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID_ERROR })));
```

**Service Code**

userId: any; // Declared as any.  If i try to make this an Observable then i get a compile error on this.userId = user.uid; in the call to afAuth saying it cannot assign string to Observable

```
userId: any;

    getCurrentUserId(): Observable<any> {

        this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(
          (user: firebase.User) => {
            if (user != null) {
              this.userId = user.uid;
              console.log('constructor auth object: ', user);
              console.log('constructor userId: ', this.userId);
            }
          });

        return this.userId;
      }
```

Comment: what do you get if you do a `.do(res => console.log(res))` before and after the `.ofType(ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID)` line?

Comment: I don't think your `this.userId` is an `Observable`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply.  I can't put it before that line as i get a compile error, but after i get Object {type: "GET_ACCOUNT_ID", payload: ""}.  I've worked out what the problem is, just not sure how to fix it.  Basically the call to auth object is a subsciption, so it returns this.userId to the effect before the subscription has finished so it is returning this.userId of undefined

Comment: Harry yes you are correct but i tried this userId: any; // Declared as any. If i try to make this an Observable then i get a compile error on this.userId = user.uid; in the call to afAuth saying it cannot assign string to Observable

Comment: why from `getCurrentUserId()` aren't you returning simply `this.afAuth.authState` that is an observable?

Comment: @crash.  The main reason for getting currentUserId is i just wanted to store the id not the whole authObject from firebase.  However if i try to return just the afAuth.authState i get a different error in my effect saying "CustomerComponent.html:1 ERROR Error: Actions may not have an undefined "type" property. Have you misspelled a constant?"  This occurs on the return from the service and before it gets back to the effect

Comment: @crash  Thank you.  I finally fixed it by returning this.afAuth.authState, but i also had to change my effect to switchMap and not map.  Not sure why this is the case will have to do some more investigation on the difference between these two operators

Comment: yes sure, you have to use `switchMap` or `flatMap` because you are returning another observable which you'll want to "chain" to the previous ones. By using `switchMap` you are resolving that observable and passing along its value. By using only `map` you will be passing along the observable itself, and not its value! Hope this makes sense

Comment: yes thank you that makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to guys for your help, the final solution was as follows: -

**Effects Code**

```js
@Effect() getAccountId$ = this.actions$
        .ofType(ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID)
        .switchMap(action =>
            this.authService.getCurrentUserId()
                .map(authObject => ({ type: ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID_SUCCESS, payload: authObject }))
                .catch(() => Observable.of({ type: ActionTypes.GET_ACCOUNT_ID_ERROR })));
```

**Service Code**

```js
getCurrentUserId(): Observable<firebase.User> {
    return this.afAuth.authState;
}
```